# Understanding degrees of freedom

Tags: statistics

Please provide guidance for the following question.

> Which of the following is/are correct?
>
> $1.$ A free particle in $\mathbb R^3$ can have infinite degrees of freedom.
>
> $2.$ The number of degree of freedom of $N$ particles is greater than $3N$.
>
> $3.$ A system of $N$ particles with $k$ constants has $3N+k$ degrees of freedom.
>
> $4.$ A system consisting of three point masses connected by three rigid massless rods has six degrees of freedom.

I think $1$st is wrong, because a particle can have max $3$ degrees of freedom, I would assume in x,y and z direction. Are all of these $3$ degrees translational? Or, one is tranlational, one rotation and one vibration?

Regarding $2$nd, I know that max degrees of freedom of N particles is $3N$, why it is so, I've no idea.

Regarding $3$rd, I am not getting what is meant by $k$ constants.

Regarding $4$th, I checked diatomic example. It has $3$ translational degrees (I assume of co-ordinates), $2$ rotational (I assume clockwise and anti-clockwise), and $1$ vibrational (I assume we have to assume that they are tied by a thread). Similarly, For $3$ particles, I would say, $3$ translational, $2$ rotational and $3$ vibrational (becasue $3$ threads).

I wish somebody could help me see clearly so that I be able to solve this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: for the third, read it as "a system of N = 1 particles with k = 3 constants has 3(1) + 3 = 6 degrees of freedom. Also, I would like to know how 2) is true.

Comment: @MathApprentice- well ya, 2) is wrong. But is 4th also wrong? because your comment suggests that 3rd is correct.